# complete noob, SOAP PHP, request with authentication, store in mySQL

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, soap

OK, so I'm completely lost here! Been staring myself blind at the screen for two days and all the explanations/tutorials I can find on the internet assumes you've already worked with SOAP before.

Using [SOAPui](http://www.soapui.org/) I was at least able to try out the request and see the result  :)  But I need to replicate this in PHP... e.g, make request in PHP using authentication credentials and then store the response in a mySQL table.

This is how the request looks like

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"    xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/">
<soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
      <tem:DoThis>
         <tem:licensId>[MYLICENSID]</tem:licensId>
         <tem:licenskey>[MYLICENSKEY]</tem:licenskey>
         <tem:guid>[AGUID]</tem:guid>
      </tem:DoThis>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

So I need to verify/authenticate the request (i guess)? But how do I do this with PHP?
Once I get the request to work, how will the response be presented? I would like to insert it into an existing mySQL DB. That is to say that this is my "end game"/the purpose of this. Retrieving information from external system, compare it to existing information in DB, and if new information exists, replace current or add new.

I tried

```
$wsdl = 'http://URLTOSERVICE/Export.svc?wsdl';
$client =
new SoapClient(
    $wsdl,
    array(
        "tem:licensid"      =>  "[MYLICENSID]",
        "tem:licenskey" =>  "[MYLICENSKEY]",
        "tem:guid"      =>  "[AGUID]"
    )
);

print_r($client->DoThis());
```

But the response is about as interesting as looking in to a blank paper for 2 days... i.e, returns nothing.

Like I said in the topic title and at the beginning. I have no experience with SOAP. So please, if some kind soul out there takes the time to answer, keep in mind that I need clear and precise explanations  :)

And thank you to anyone taking the time to help me understanding this...

Answer (score 0):

can you indicate the WSDL url? I would suggest you to try a WSDL to php converter to see more clearly how to call the SOAP Web service.
To set credentials as the request you indicate, you must use the Soapheader class, http://php.net/manual/fr/class.soapheader.php, and call the __setSoapheaders, http://www.php.net/manual/fr/soapclient.setsoapHeaders.php, before calling the operation.
Let me know if you need any help or a WSDL to php converter.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I googled WSDL to PHP converter, but can't make sense of anything I find... Like I said, with the soapUI I was at least able to simply make the request and view the response. How can this be done with PHP?

Comment: Have you tried with https://github.com/mikaelcom/WsdlToPhp usable on https://www.wsdltophp.com. In any case, at this time, there is not such system as SOAPUI in PHP, you have to develop the code yourself.